# laravel not execute after adding SSL

Tags: apache-httpd, ssl, amazon-ec2

I'm trying to run laravel on EC2(AWS linux 2) and apache server. And I recently bought a domain from Namecheap

[image]

And I installed laravel to var/www/html folder.

My **/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf** has those lines,

```
DocumentRoot "/var/www/html/public"

<Directory "/var/www/html">

    AllowOverride All

    #
    # Controls who can get stuff from this server.
    #
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

And this is my **/etc/httpd/conf.d/vhost.conf** is this

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

  ServerName mydomain.store

  ServerAlias https://www.mydomain.store

  DocumentRoot /var/www/html/public

  ServerAdmin mailto:info@backpackadvisor.com

  
  <Directory /var/www/html>
    AllowOverride All
  </Directory>

RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =mydomain.store [OR]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =https://www.mydomain.store
RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,NE,R=permanent]
</VirtualHost>
```

And I added SSL via `sudo certbot --apache`

And when I add like this in browser (Not real IP) http://18.181.183.11/ my app works fine.
But when I add **https://mydomain.store** in browser I get file structure like this,

[image]

And when I add **https://mydomain.store/public** in browser app works.

Does anyone know why?

Answer (score 0):

After lots of effort find the answer myself. Posting it thinking it may help someone like me in the future.

I used **Let’s Encrypt** for creating ssl and it automatically create an virtual host for port 443 (https) inside `vhost-le-ssl.conf` file.

So we need to access the file,

```
sudo vi /etc/httpd/conf.d/vhost-le-ssl.conf
```

And change document root there to (point to public folder),

```
DocumentRoot /var/www/html/public
```

And restart apache after that.